# C++ calculating the payout on an odds-based game

Tags: c++

I've been trying for the past couple of weeks to multiply a double (e.g 2.76) by an int to produce results but the end result is always rounded up as an int of course and double isn't always precise enough as we know already.  I'm not an expert, and I've never had to face precision math honestly before with C++ I'm used to PHP.  As over-asked as I'm sure this is (I've googled and searched here but haven't come up with any solution - maybe I'm not understanding it properly); would someone mind lending a hand?

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double decdouble = 2.72;
int multiby = decdouble * 10127;
couut << "Result: " << multiby << endl;
```

Now if I only wanted to output to stdout that would be alright I suppose and I could use setprecision(), but I need to reference this in other areas of the code which I'm not sure I'd be able to specify precision saved to a variable.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `int multiby = decdouble * 10127;` you're assigning it to an `int` and thats where the rounding happens. Assign instead to a `double` and you'll get a more expected result - `double multiby = decdouble * 10127;`

Comment: *"double isn't always precise enough as we know already"* isn't precise enough for what?

Comment: What do you mean with "precision math"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use double instead of int for your multiplication, for the result to be precise, because int returns the closest number to an int from your multiplication.

```
#include <iostream> /// you don't really need the other libraries you included

using namespace std; /// use this namespace to avoid std:: for each line

int main() /// if you want your code to run, add it in the main() function
{
  double decdouble = 2.72;
  double multiby = decdouble * 10127; /// use double, not int for a precise result
  cout <<"Result: "<< multiby << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.  Don't just dump code and say "Try this".

Comment: @zero298 is it ok now? Thanks for telling me

Comment: Yes, thank you.  To be honest, it was difficult to tell the difference between your original code and the OP's.  You might even want to add a comment on the line to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks, I have just started using stackoverflow to help others, I will keep this in mind